# Isn't $\frac{ax+bi}{ax+bi}$ equal to $1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

Isn’t $\dfrac{ax+bi}{ax+bi}$ equal to $1$?
Here, $i=\sqrt{-1}$, & $a$,$b$ & $x$ $\in$ $R$

Comment: Yes, unless $ax+bi = 0$.

Comment: I suppose $a,$ $b,$ and $x$ all are meant to be real numbers, but I think it would be better to make that explicit. I don't know of any ironclad rule that says one can never use any of those symbols to represent a complex number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Division in the field of complex numbers is defined in the following manner:
$\frac{ax+bi}{ax+bi}=\frac{(ax+bi)(ax-bi)}{(ax+bi)(ax-bi)}$, so
$\frac{ax+bi}{ax+bi}=\frac{a^2x^2+b^2}{a^2x^2+b^2}$, which is a real number and equal to 1. Hence your intuition is correct. But note that this is not true for $b=0$ and either $a=0$ or $x=0$ or both. Because $\frac{a^2x^2+b^2}{a^2x^2+b^2}$ is not defined when $b=0$ and either $a=0$ or $x=0$ or both.

Comment: What's the reason for multiplying by the conjugate? The fact that $z/z=1$ (for $z\ne0$) is simply the definition of inverse element.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that at least one of $ax$ and $b$ is non-zero, then yes. The complex numbers under the usual operations of addition and multiplication form a field.

Comment: This is incorrect as written. What if $a=1,x=0,b=0$?

Answer (score 0):

In the complex field, every nonzero complex number $z$ has an inverse $z^{-1}$. It is customary to write
$$
wz^{-1}=\frac{w}{z}
$$
By definition, $zz^{-1}=1$, so in the alternative notation
$$
\frac{z}{z}=1
$$
*for every complex number $z\ne0$*.

Now take $z=ax+bi$ and you have your result. Of course, if $ax+bi=0$ (that is, $ax=0$ and $b=0$), the expression $(ax+bi)/(ax+bi)$ is undefined.